# using a timeout and scope apply - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've just come on board to a new project and I see this pattern alot in angular js code:

```
_.defer(function () {
$scope.$apply();
});
```

This seems wrong to me but I'm not sure why. What are possible reasons that you would you wait for angular's interpolation to finish and then call $scope.$apply() again?

Comment: maybe to avoid the error "digest already in progress". A variable can be changed while Angular is "digesting" the data. so maybe this change can be not detected by angular so an "$apply" is needed. My 2cents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$apply()` calls `$digest()`

Under the hood, $digest is angular's internal loop to check if any binded data has changed.
Most of the time, you don't need to call $apply yourself because AngularJS takes care of this.

The only cases you need to call $apply is when you use an external lib (for instance when you wrap a jquery lib inside a directive or when using a asynchronous lib such as facebook/twitter) and angular could not possibly know about the DOM changes.

In these cases, you could wrap your code inside `$timeout`. It is just a safe way for angular to call $apply when its ready rather than risking the error `'$digest already in progress error'` is you directly call $apply.

```
$timeout (function () {
  $scope.update = "something has changed";
});
```

This way is more the native angular way rather than using the underscore library.

For detailed explanations you can check out [this article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) (a bit old but the core principles of angular stay the same).